# Rails I18n, interpolation when we ask to receive a hash object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have an issue with the interpolation of value in my strings, i ask for the related_links strings and i receive a hash with the title and the url.

this is my .yml

```
     user:
      subject: "New project created: %{title}"
      related_links:
        - title: Project Created
          url: 'projects/%{id}'
```

When i ask for `I18n.t("user.releated_links", id: xx)` I get

```
{title: "Project Created", url: "projects/%{id}"}
```

DO any of you know how i can pass my parameters to related_links and it can interpolate the strings in the hash ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to use `I18n.t("user.releated_links.url", id: xx)`.

You are missing the last key.

As a side note: Are you sure you want to generate URL from the localization files? Assuming those are links within your application, why don't you better use the rails helpers?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still want the bellow output

```
{title: "Project Created", url: "projects/%{id}"}
```

Use `deep_interpolate` option

`I18n.t("user.releated_links", deep_interpolation: true, id: xx)`

`Output => {title: "Project Created", url: "projects/xx"}`